# Comment analyser « dont a fait l'objet » ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, pronoms-relatifs

Dans un commentaire d'Air Canada sous [cette vidéo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgDizh4DMno):

> Nous désirons présenter nos ‎excuses pour le traitement tout à fait inacceptable **dont a fait l'objet** les bagages de nos passagers.  Les employés impliqués ont été suspendus et avisés qu'ils seront licenciés une fois l'enquête interne complétée.
>
> La version anglaise: We would like to apologize for the totally unacceptable mishandling of our passengers' baggage captured on video.

Comment analyser la phrase en gras? Quel est l'objet? Quel est l'antécédent de **dont**, dont l'usage implique l'existence d'un verbe suivi de la préposition « de » ? Quel est ce verbe ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il y a une faute de grammaire (le commentaire a probablement été rédigé ou traduit un peu vite) : la phrase devrait être

> Nous désirons présenter nos ‎excuses pour le traitement tout à fait inacceptable dont **ont** fait l'objet les bagages de nos passagers.

Le sujet du verbe est « les bagages de nos passagers ». Les bagages ont **fait l'objet d'**un traitement tout à fait inacceptable.

Le pronom relatif *dont* peut remplacer un complément de nom, pas seulement un complément d'objet indirect.

Comment: Je conviens qu'il y a une faute de grammaire, mais j'ose dire que "dont ont fait l'objet" ne marche pas non plus... il faudrait dire "dont les bagages... ont été l'objet."  Construction: "vous avez été l'objet d'un cambriolage"...

Comment: @mikerodent Pourquoi ? Je ne vois pas de différence entre « faire l'objet de » et « être l'objet de », et [la BDL on plus](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3977).

Comment: tu es francophone, moi pas, donc je cède à ta conviction.  Mais d'abord pour moi "dont ont" est une combinaison difficile et lourde: le singulier, lui, "dont a fait l'objet" est plus acceptable du point de vue de l'euphonie.  Mais je pense aussi qu'il existe une différence entre "faire l'objet de" et "être l'objet de" - extrêmement difficile à cerner (pour moi) !  Mais je pense que, même si on allait utiliser "faire l'objet", rien que par souci d'euphonie je préférerais dire "dont les bagages... ont fait l'objet".

Comment: Cette différence: pour moi "faire l'objet" est plus large, et synonyme de l'anglais "form the subject of X".  Par contre "être l'objet" est, je pense, nécessairement passif, et synonyme de "be the subject of X".  Hypothèse. Qu'en pense-t-on ?

Comment: @mikerodent Je ne vois aucune raison euphonique d'éviter « dont ont » (et [la littérature non plus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dont+a+fait+l%27objet+%2F+a+fait+l%27objet%2Cdont+ont+fait+l%27objet+%2F+ont+fait+l%27objet&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28dont%20a%20fait%20l%27%20objet%20/%20a%20fait%20l%27%20objet%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28dont%20ont%20fait%20l%27%20objet%20/%20ont%20fait%20l%27%20objet%29%3B%2Cc0)).

Comment: @mikerodent Le verbe peut être après le pronom ou après le sujet ; ici, j'ai une légère préférence pour le verbe au début, à cause de la présence de deux noms pluriels qui rend la phrase « … dont les bagages de nos passagers ont fait l'objet » plus difficile à analyser. En règle générale, je crois qu'on évite en français un sujet trop long dans une relative, il y a une certaine impatience à voir arriver le verbe. Si tu veux continuer la discussion sur la différence, je te conseille le [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette), ou pose la question sur le site.

Comment: @Gilles - C'est étrange, bien que je sois d'accord avec tes arguments, je suis aussi en phase avec *mike rodent* sur le problème d'euphonie : si *dont on* (qui ouvre vers *dondon, tonton, pompon* ..) est lisible dans un libre technique ou scientifique, je me sens incapable de l'employer dans un texte soutenu, pour ester en justice par exemple, ou pour l'employer dans tout endroit où la qualité de l'oralité importe autant que la puissance argumentaire.